# QtSql: binding doesn't change query with SQLite

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtsql

I have the following code that's supposed to bind a value to a prepare statement:

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.setForwardOnly(true);
query.prepare("SELECT Entry.* FROM Entry WHERE body LIKE ?;");
query.addBindValue(QVariant("%" + name + "%"));
query.exec();
tDebug("%s", query.executedQuery().toUtf8().data());
```

For instance, if `name` was `"thing"`, then the query should execute the statement `SELECT Entry.* FROM Entry WHERE body LIKE "%thing%"`, but it executes `SELECT Entry.* FROM Entry WHERE body LIKE ?`, almost as if the bound value was ignored. Named placeholders have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on an equivalent example and appropriately testing the result of "prepare" and "exec", which both return a Boolean. I tested that the values are bounded ok after exec with:

```
  QList<QVariant> list = query.boundValues().values();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    qDebug() << i << ": " << list.at(i).toString();
```

I tested that I got the expected result with

```
  while (query.next())
    qDebug()<<"result = "<<query.value(0);
```

Indeed, the `executedQuery` did not contain the bounded values, but the comment in Qt is somewhat vague on this:

"If a prepared query with placeholders is executed on a DBMS that does not support it, the preparation of this query is emulated.The placeholders in the original query are replaced with their bound values to form a new query. This function returns the modified query. It is mostly useful for debugging purposes."

So I assume that for postgresql (what I have) and SQLite, the `executedQuery` does return the original with placeholders and not bounded values.

Comment: I was looking more for how to make QtSql actually bind the values.

Comment: The way I interpret the documentation, that only becomes visible in latestQuery or executedQuery for databases that have no support for placeholders.

Comment: But then, `executedQuery` should still return the modified query, right?

Comment: @bb94, the idea here is that names get actually bound in database engines that support prepared statements, otherwise Qt emulates that by binding names in the driver. When binding happens in the database, there is no way for Qt to return the executedStatement after binding, it can only do so when binding happens on Qt's side (when there is no support for prepared statements in the DB engine). This is why [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#executedQuery) says that a replaced string is returned only when using a DB engine that does not support prepared statements...